# Insert data from applet textfield to mysql database - error

Tags: java, mysql, applet

What I am trying to do is to add data on mysql database using my applet page. my idea is to fill up the textfields then when i hit the save button all the text's will add to mySQL database. But i'm having an error saying

```
Access Denied: java.security.AccessControlException:access denied 
    (java.io.FilePermision "\C:\Program Files(x86)\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-5.1.30\mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar‌​" "read")
```

thank you in advance.  here's my code: :((

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.sql.*;
import java.net.*;



public class AddBook extends JApplet
{
    JButton btnSave, btnCancel;
    JLabel lblIsbn, lblTitle, lblCategory, lblAuthor, lblYPublish, lblPublisher, lblCopies, lblYear, lblMsg1;
    JTextField txtTitle, txtCategory;
    JTextField txtIsbn, txtAuthor, txtPublisher, txtCopies, txtYear;

    String ttitle, tauthor, tpublisher, tcategory, tisbn, tyear, tqty;

    public void init()
    {
        Font fonttxt = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 16);
        Font fontlbl = new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD, 14);
        Font fontbtn = new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD, 16);
        Font fontTitle = new Font("Arial ",Font.BOLD,30);

        setLayout(null);
        setSize(410, 400);

        setBackground(Color.gray);

        btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.setFont(fontbtn);
        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.setFont(fontbtn);

        lblMsg1 = new JLabel ("ADD BOOK");
        lblMsg1.setFont(fontbtn);
        lblIsbn = new JLabel("ISBN :");
        lblIsbn.setFont(fontlbl);
        lblTitle = new JLabel ("Title :");
        lblTitle.setFont(fontlbl);
        lblCategory = new JLabel ("Category :");
        lblCategory.setFont(fontlbl);
        lblAuthor = new JLabel ("Author :");
        lblAuthor.setFont(fontlbl);
        lblYear = new JLabel ("Year Published :");
        lblYear.setFont(fontlbl);
        lblPublisher = new JLabel ("Publisher :");
        lblPublisher.setFont(fontlbl);
        lblCopies = new JLabel ("Number of Copies :");
        lblCopies.setFont(fontlbl);

        JTextField txtIsbn = new JTextField ("",100);
        txtIsbn.setFont(fonttxt);
        JTextField txtTitle = new JTextField ("",100);
        txtTitle.setFont(fonttxt);
        JTextField txtCategory = new JTextField ("",100);
        txtCategory.setFont(fonttxt);
        JTextField txtAuthor = new JTextField ("",100);
        txtAuthor.setFont(fonttxt);
        JTextField txtPublisher = new JTextField ("",100);
        txtPublisher.setFont(fonttxt);
        JTextField txtCopies = new JTextField ("",100);
        txtCopies.setFont(fonttxt);
        JTextField txtYear = new JTextField ("",100);
        txtYear.setFont(fonttxt);

        lblMsg1.setBounds(10,10,200,40);
        lblIsbn.setBounds(10,50,250,30);
        txtIsbn.setBounds(130,50,250,30);
        lblTitle.setBounds(10,90,250,30);
        txtTitle.setBounds(130,90,250,30); 
        lblCategory.setBounds(10,130,250,30);
        txtCategory.setBounds(130,130,250,30); 
        lblAuthor.setBounds(10,165,250,30);
        txtAuthor.setBounds(130,165,250,30);  
        lblPublisher.setBounds(10,200,250,30);
        txtPublisher.setBounds(130,200,250,30);
        lblCopies.setBounds(10,240,250,30);
        txtCopies.setBounds(130,240,250,30);
        lblYear.setBounds(10,280,250,30);
        txtYear.setBounds(130,280,250,30);
        btnSave.setBounds(40,320,150,35);
        btnCancel.setBounds(200,320,150,35);

        add(lblMsg1);
        add(txtIsbn);
        add(txtTitle);
        add(txtCategory);
        add(txtAuthor);
        add(txtPublisher);
        add(txtCopies);
        add(txtYear);
        add(lblIsbn);
        add(lblTitle);
        add(lblCategory);
        add(lblAuthor);
        add(lblPublisher);
        add(lblCopies);
        add(lblYear);

        add(btnSave);
        add(btnCancel);



        tisbn = txtIsbn.getText();
        tyear = txtYear.getText();
        tqty = txtCopies.getText();
        ttitle = txtTitle.getText();
        tauthor = txtAuthor.getText();
        tcategory = txtCategory.getText();
        tpublisher = txtPublisher.getText();

        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {

                //Connection con = null;
                //Statement st = null;   1
                PreparedStatement pstmt;
                Connection con; 

                if(ae.getSource() == btnSave)
                {


                    try {

                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/library_system", "root", "password");

                        con.setAutoCommit(false);


                        pstmt = con.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO book_records VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); 

                        pstmt.setString(1, tisbn);
                        pstmt.setString(2, ttitle);
                        pstmt.setString(3, tauthor);
                        pstmt.setString (4, tyear);
                        pstmt.setString(5, tpublisher);
                        pstmt.setString(6, tcategory);
                        pstmt.setString(7, tqty);

                        pstmt.executeUpdate();

                        con.commit();
                        pstmt.close();

                    }
                    catch(Exception err)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access Denied: "+err );
                    }
                }

               }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Should show us the full stack trace of error!

Comment: the full error says 

"Access Denied: java.security.AccessControlException:access denied ("java.io.FilePermision" "\C:\Program Files(x86)\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-5.1.30\mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar" "read")

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the mysql connection as

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username",    "password");
```

I think you are missing port.

Answer (score 0):

The error says simply "Access denied" problem from your Java program to the directory where MySQL jar exists.
You shouldn't link (reference) jar file in another directory from Java application.

The problem can be simply solved by adding the required `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar‌​` to your application's class path.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it. I've already download and install it i've tried but still got the same problem. i am using windows 8 64bit. On mySQL download it only have the 32 bit. do you have any suggestion?.

Comment: What error says more after adding `mysql-connector` jar to application class path?